# Trouble Displaying Images On Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I'm working on my first IOS app. The app downloads and displays data from a database via a PHP web page. That's all working fine. I also grab an image from the same web server to display in a UIImageView. This all works on fine on the Simulator.

On my test device (a 3GS), everything works except I cannot get the downloaded image to display in my UIImageView.

If there is no internet connection, I am able to display my alternate image that I've included in app's bundle on the simulator and on the device.

```
// Inside My data class Implementation
- (void)setUpTheData
{
--- other code ---

NSURL *myImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myImageURLString];
NSData *myImageRawData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myImageURL];
self.myImageData = myImageRawData;

}

- (NSData*)getTheImageData
{
    return _myImageData;
}

// Inside my viewDidLoad
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[theRemoteData getTheImageData]];
_testImage.image = theImage;
```

I've compared the image data from both the simulator and the device and they are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set a weak pointer in my imageData property in my data class. Changing to strong fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad maybe?

Comment: Also double check any background process code as updates to the UI need to happen on the main thread. Is anything returning asynchronously which could be causing this? Not sure this has anything to do with it, but when I run into inexplicably odd stuff like this I've found it's often thread or synchronicity related.

Comment: Thanks Monte. Your first suggestion didn't work. Back to the drawing board. I'll look into your other suggestions.